# Fill the non-standard shape WPF window with an image

Tags: wpf, image-processing

I have created a non standard shaped window with the

```
WindowStyle="None" 
AllowsTransparency="True" 
Background="Transparent"
```

approach.

I have arrived at the following:

[image]

A windows has a grid. The grid has an Image control (a superman logo) and a border control (blue panel) that will in turn contain listbox that is not yet visible due to the absense of elements.

At some point I need to fill an entire window with a patter, so I woul arrive at something like this:

[image]

If I just fill separate controls with a pattern, it wouldn't appear to be smoothly distributed along the page.

So my idea is to somehow dynamically get the path element out of the window and fill it with a pattern I need, and then display.

Can this be done via code at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx) is probably the easiest way I know of, and is what I usually do for non-standard window shapes

Comment: Ok, but how do I get a Path object from a Window at runtime? That was basically the question?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov In the past I actually calculate the `Path` prior to run-time and hard-code it in

Comment: ok, how can I determine the Path points with a window I have? Do you know a way to do it, maybe, in Expression Blend? How did you used to do it?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov Ummmm... trial and error? :) Actually I believe you can use Expression Blend for it, but I never have. I usually just set the Path's Data property using the following link as a reference guide. I find them pretty easy to draw, especially once you realize that using a lower case letter will give you a relative segment instead of needing to specify absolute x,y coordinates for everything http://rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language/